# For input string: "".I have tried it many times but cant get solution

Tags: android

I tried to get string value from shared preference and set it in text view. I also convert this string value into integer and set it in progress bar progress value.

I cant understand this. code worked 2 days ago but it doesn't this time properly. I have tried it many times but cant get the real problem and solution.

```
package com.example.pushups;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TrainingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static String t;
    static Integer tt;
    public static final String SHARED_PREF2="shared";
    public static final String TEXT2="text";
    static ProgressBar progressBarTraining;
    static TextView ProgressText,ProgresDaysLeft;
    static int progressSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);

        ProgresDaysLeft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.daysLeft);
        ProgressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.proText);
        progressBarTraining=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
        btn_day1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d1);
        btn_day2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d2);
        btn_day3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d3);
        btn_day4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d4);
        btn_day5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d5);
        btn_day6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d6);
        btn_day7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.d7);

        progressBarTraining.setProgress(0);

        update();
    }

    public void update() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF2,MODE_PRIVATE);
        t=sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT2,"");
        Toast.makeText(this, t.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ProgressText.setText(t);
        progressBarTraining.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(t));
        tt=Integer.valueOf(t);



        if (tt==0){
            ProgressText.setText("0%");
        }
        else if (tt==15){
            ProgressText.setText("15%");
        }
        else if (tt==30){
            ProgressText.setText("30%");
        }
        else if (tt==45){
            ProgressText.setText("45%");
        }
        else if (tt==60){
            ProgressText.setText("60%");
        }
        else if (tt==75){
            ProgressText.setText("75%");
        }
        else if (tt==90){
            ProgressText.setText("90%");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you didn't mention the problem you are facing? what exception you are getting?

Comment: I dont know why it happens . It just send me for input string error.

Comment: please add thje exception you are facing. You can find it in android studio, in the bottom-left tab named "run", after you install and run your application.

Comment: ok wait i can send it here

Comment: My problem is solved. Im very thankful for your guideness

Comment: Did you know your whole `if...else if` code block can be replaced with one single line of code like: `ProgressText.setText(tt + "%");` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void update() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF2,MODE_PRIVATE);
        t=sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT2,"");
        Toast.makeText(this, t.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (t.isEmpty()){
            ProgressText.setText("dara");
            progressBarTraining.setProgress(0);
            tt=0;
        }else {
            ProgressText.setText(t);
            progressBarTraining.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(t));
            tt=Integer.valueOf(t);

            if (tt==0){
                ProgressText.setText("0%");
            }
            else if (tt==15){
                ProgressText.setText("15%");
            }
            else if (tt==30){
                ProgressText.setText("30%");
            }
            else if (tt==45){
                ProgressText.setText("45%");
            }
            else if (tt==60){
                ProgressText.setText("60%");
            }
            else if (tt==75){
                ProgressText.setText("75%");
            }
            else if (tt==90){
                ProgressText.setText("90%");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see some problems here:

1. variables pointing to screen views (TextView, ProgressBar etc) should not be static. When the activity will be destroyed and those will be out of the screen, your program will still hold a reference to them - preventing the garbage-collector from deleting them and freeing the memory.
2. `btn_day1`, `btn_day2` etc are not defined anywhere, It is a miracle that your app can still compile :P
3. in this line: `t=sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT2,"");` you assign `t` with the string previously stored in the SP, or **empty string** if nothing is stored.
   If nothing is stored, this empty string will cause the later-on line `tt=Integer.valueOf(t);` to crash your app - with an exception stating that `"" could not be converted to an int`. I would assign a different default value such as `"0"` or `String.format(Int.MIN_VALUE)`.